# Nginx shared directives

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

Moving now from apache to nginx, also rewriting .htaccess to nginx.
I have such "problem":

I have about ten sites, that utilize same core.
So I have a bunch of rewrite rules that should go to each of one of them. 
Moreover, number of sites will be added, as well as number of common rules.

In apache i've used to write all common directives to global /www folder when all websites are placed.

But for now, in nginx i cant determine how should i organize config file.

I have about 10 common rules and 30 per-site rules for every site.

So have no idea, how to NOT to write 10 common rules to each config and in the same time to provide each site with his own rules.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new file in `/etc/nginx` containing your shared directives, and then [include](http://nginx.org/r/include) them in each site's configuration.

The config files which ship with nginx include an example of this: `fastcgi_params` contains shared directives that are used in various configuration files where they call `include fastcgi_params;`.

Comment: Thanks  This is simple.. By the way, do you know how nginx handles includes? I mean, if there are lot of includes this mean that in memory stored lots of duplicates or I have nothing to worry about?